# Integrate Facebook with Phongap

Tags: facebook, cordova

I integrated my app with Facebook using https://github.com/pc035860/angular-easyfb#configuration Everything is completed and works fine with web browser. How can i mould the same code to work with phonegap and use it with android phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with web and fb js integration, however Facebook highly recommends usage of their native SDK's in mobile platforms. It adds integration with the Facebook app installed on user devices for authentication and favoured by users and Facebook afaik.

Anyhow, you have cordova/phonegap plugins to integrate facebook, just do a search on plugreg: http://plugreg.com/search?q=facebook

PS: I am one of the developers of the following Facebook plugin by the way: http://plugreg.com/plugin/ccsoft/cordova-facebook

Comment: Do i have to change the code after using the plugin? Sorry for this silly question but i am really a newbie at this and never used a plugin with cordova phonegap

Comment: Yes you should. Each plugin comes with its own set of js functions usually. The top rated, official facebook plugin tries to wrap the same FB js api, so it might be a better choice if you want to preserve your js code (although I wouldn't recommend it, see bottom of the readme at our plugin page for details).